# how to make arrow thinner matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot an arrow as below, whilst I think it's a little bit big. How can I make it thinner and smaller? Thank you

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.annotate(df.index[i],xy=(x[i],y[i]),xytext=(x[i]+1.31,y[i]-0.55),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='blue', shrink=0.1))
```

Comment: Maybe try something like adding `markersize=0.1` to the dict?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try adjusting the `width` parameter (from the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate))

```
plt.annotate(df.index[i], 
    xy=(x[i],y[i]), xytext=(x[i]+1.31,y[i]-0.55),
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='blue', shrink=0.1, width=2)
)
```

I've adjusted your snippet to make the parameter more obvious. Note also that `width` is in points, so you may need to try a few different values out. Other values worth looking at are `frac`. `headwidth` and `shrink` ([also in the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate)), especially if you want to make the head smaller too!

Comment: Width goes in arrowprops in python 2.7 ```plt.annotate(df.index[i], 
    xy=(x[i],y[i]), xytext=(x[i]+1.31,y[i]-0.55),
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='blue', shrink=0.1, width=2),
)```